# How to customize apply_filters to not include oembed

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use apply_filters, but in some cases I don't want it to use oembed to auto-embed the YouTube videoes, but just showing them as links. Is there an easy way to add some paramters or so?

This is how it looks now:

```
<?php echo apply_filters("the_content", $result->text); ?>
```

Comment: You should be able to run [wp_oembed_remove_provider()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_remove_provider) before the above, by specifying YouTube as the provider to remove.

Comment: Tried adding `wp_oembed_remove_provider('#https://(www\.)?youtube\.com/watch.*#i')`, which should be the correct format for my links. Still not working.